# Animating a UIImageView off the screen

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, uiview, uiimageview

I have a `UIImageView` that I need to animate off the screen. I'm doing this by adjusting the frame to 0 in a 1 second animation block.  If I leave the content type alone, which is one of the scaling types, it will shrink to 0 as I want it to, but it will pinch the image as it adjusts to the new frame size. **I need it to just crop the bottom off instead**. I changed the content type to top left and that causes it to not do anything.
What am I missing here?

Here's the animation block code.

```
// Change frame height.
[UIView animateWithDuration:1.0f
                 animations:^ {
                     // Animate the frame off the screen
                     _closeImage.frame = CGRectMake(_closeImage.frame.origin.x, _closeImage.frame.origin.y, _closeImage.frame.size.width, 0);
                 }
 ];
```

Comment: what do you mean by content type?

Comment: He means the scale mode. @btate, try the other scaleModes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to change the `scaleMode` property. You can change it to aspect fit if you want it to shrink while scaling correctly. Otherwise, you can try some of the other ones.

**EDIT:**

As per your comment, you need to set the `clipsToBounds` property.

Comment: @Moshe Do you mean `contentMode`?

Comment: I'm changing the content mode.  If I do something other than a scaling one the frame height does not change at all.  I'm currently using top left. _closeImage.contentMode = UIViewContentModeTopLeft;

Comment: Do you change it inside or outside of the animation block? Also, try reloading the image right after changing the content mode before you animate. That might help by forcing the correct mode.

Comment: I'm doing it outside the animation block.

Comment: `_closeImage.frame = self.frame;
    _closeImage.contentMode = UIViewContentModeTopLeft;
    
    // Add as subview
    [self.superview addSubview:_closeImage];
    
    // Remove this from the super view
    [self removeFromSuperview];
    
    // Change frame height.
    [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0f
                     animations:^ {
                         // Animate the frame off the screen
                         _closeImage.frame = CGRectMake(_closeImage.frame.origin.x, _closeImage.frame.origin.y, _closeImage.frame.size.width, 0);
                     }
     ];`

Comment: Got it.  I was missing _closeImage.clipsToBounds = YES;

Answer (score 0):

You can try with:

```
    // Change frame placement.
[UIView animateWithDuration:1.0f
                 animations:^ {
                     // Animate the frame off the screen
                     _closeImage.frame = CGRectMake(_closeImage.frame.origin.x, _parentView.frame.size.height, _closeImage.frame.size.width, _closeImage.frame.size.height);
                 }
 ];
```

_parentView is view containing imageview... it will slide off parentView, and consider removing it from superview afterwards if you dont use it anymore...

Comment: There's a toolbar at the top of the parent view.  I'm looking for more of an effect as if the image is rolling out of and into the toolbar.  So I just need the frame to animate to 0 and crop out anything that doesn't fit.

Comment: So set toolbar to be on top of an image view and change origin of image to be:
CGRectMake(_closeImage.frame.origin.x, -_closeImage.frame.size.height, _closeImage.frame.size.width, _closeImage.frame.size.height);

Why shrinking image when you can move it off screen...